# Pip install Pillow: "no module named Pillow?"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

```
user$ sudo pip install -U Pillow
...
Requirement already up-to-date: Pillow in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

>>> import Pillow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Pillow
```

I've installed Pillow six ways from Sunday, using all sorts of forms of `pip` and `sudo`, even changing directory access permissions several times (`chown`), but can't get it to properly import. How can I get this to work?

Edit: I've even got this error before (that's why I tried `chown`)

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL'
```

Comment: There is no need to use `chown`. You are just importing the wrong name.

Comment: But, I've used `sudo -m pip install Pillow` every time.

Comment: Yes, so? You still need to use `import PIL`, not `import Pillow`.

Comment: Oh, alright. Thanks for your help.