# Installed PILLOW Module is not Identifying to Import in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-import, python-module

I have installed the PILLOW module in Windows 8.1 for Python 3 using the below command.

```
pip install pillow
```

The installation was a success.

Unfortunately when I tried to import the image sub-module within it using the below statement I got an import error.

```
from PIL import image
```

**Error:** ImportError: cannot import name 'image' from 'PIL' (C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL_*init*_.py)

Although the below statement is giving me an error for the 'PIL' .

```
image = PIL.Image.open("Capture Image.PNG")
```

**Error:** Undefined variable: ' PIL'Python(undefined-variable)

I have tried similar posts listed below, but they didn't help me to solve the issue.

1. [Pip install Pillow: "no module named Pillow?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698339/pip-install-pillow-no-module-named-pillow)
2. [Pillow installed, but getting "no module named pillow" when importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834663/pillow-installed-but-getting-no-module-named-pillow-when-importing)
3. [Python pillow module not importing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63743467/python-pillow-module-not-importing-properly)

Could you please someone explain what I'm missing here?

Regards,
Chiranthaka

Comment: I can't understand the issue with this question. Still no one answered this.

Comment: isn't it `from PIL import Image`? Note the uppercase `I` of `Image`.

Comment: Also please learn the basics of python first before doing anything else. You imported `Image` not `PIL` so `image = Image.open("Capture Image.PNG")`.

Comment: It worked. Thanks @dragon2fly

Actually I'm learning the basics. That's how I ran into this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dragon2fly Many thanks for solving the issue. Please refer the below snippet for the complete source code.

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("Capture_image.png")

print(image.size)
```